# Can no longer connect to VPN

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, networkmanager

I have had a working VPN connection for the last several years that mysteriously stopped working yesterday.

```
nmcli con up id <myconnection>
Error: Connection activation failed: Unknown reason
```

There is another question discussing this specific error message [here](https://superuser.com/q/602490).
Most of the suggested solutions boil down to a wrong password. However, in my case, the password is stored in a file that I haven't changed, and also the password is not due to expire for several months. I have also not updated my system (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS) since the last time I connected 10 days ago, so there should not have been a breaking change in `networkmanager`.

The VPN is up and running according to the status page, and I can ping the server just fine.

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog -n 30
```

showed the following entries in the syslog:

```
Mar 23 14:35:47 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510147.8744] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88" name="<myconnection>" pid=14976 uid=1000 result="success"
Mar 23 14:35:47 paul-XPS-15-9560 gnome-shell[1181]: JS ERROR: TypeError: item is undefined#012setActiveConnections/<@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1520:17#012setActiveConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1517:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncVpnConnections@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1855:9#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Mar 23 14:35:47 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510147.8844] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 14982
Mar 23 14:35:47 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510147.9027] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connection
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.0024] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.0024] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) reply received
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.0571] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 systemd-udevd[14994]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.0830] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.0830] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: server requested domain, but none set (use "Domain ..." in config or --domain
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 gnome-shell[2866]: Removing a network device that was not added
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 gnome-shell[1181]: Removing a network device that was not added
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.2385] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <warn>  [1616510148.2551] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <warn>  [1616510148.2552] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.2552] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.2554] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
Mar 23 14:35:48 paul-XPS-15-9560 NetworkManager[1018]: <info>  [1616510148.2574] vpn-connection[0x5654f4a8c5d0,1bfc80fc-f18e-4f33-9e2f-41a90d650d88,"<myconnection>",0]: VPN service disappeared
```

To my untrained eye, the smoking gun seems to be this line:

```
/usr/sbin/vpnc: server requested domain, but none set (use "Domain ..." in config or --domain
```

However, I don't understand what that could refer to as there is no corresponding entry under Settings>Network>VPN>MyConnection>Identity, where all other access information (gateway/user name/user password/group name/group password) is otherwise stored.

Any advice that would help me resolve or further triage this issue would be much appreciated.

Comment: See if [post1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077671/gnome-network-manager-failing-to-connect) or [post2](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-pptp/+bug/1725779) are relevant.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you for the links. Unfortunately, I don't think they are relevant. In post1, the user had no working installation of a VPN client. In post2, the authentication binary could not be accessed. Neither is the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else comes across this problem:

The issue appears to be that the protocol changed server-side.

The "Domain" argument is not used by my VPN. If the "Domain" keyword is unset, some user-side VPN clients send --domain "" (an empty string). Other VPN clients, simply do not specify the Domain argument at all. `networkmanager` falls into the latter category.

As I was able to access the VPN prior to the last couple of days, not specifying the "Domain" argument presumably was a valid way to access the VPN. As the log indicates, this is no longer the case. If I force an empty string for the Domain argument, I can connect using vpnc:

```
sudo vpnc-connect <myconnection> --domain ""
```

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to force `networkmanager` to send an empty string: [link to issue on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-vpnc/+bug/1197313)